# How to hide a button in Silverlight/WP7?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I saw a question here showing to use this:

```
button.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
```

but I only have Collapsed or Visible, and Collapsed removes the button which changes the layout of the controls which I don't want.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another solution if you don't want to resort to changing the Opacity would be encapsulate the button within a Grid and set the Grid height property to fixed size corresponding to the button height. Now you can Collapse the button without other controls rearranging themselves.

Cheers, 
Anders

Answer (score 4):

Apparently you are on the `Silverlight` framework which doesnT have the `Hidden` option.

> Silverlight does not support the Hidden Visibility state.

You can see the available members in both .Net framework and Silverlight [in the reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.visibility%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) . (use the dropdown on top of the page to switch between different platforms)

A crooked solution to your problem could be setting the `opacity` of the UI element to `0` but this approach is known to have performance drawbacks.

Comment: Thanks so there is no way to hide a button without collapsing in SL?

Comment: Thanks, I actually just did opacity to 0 as well. It's only 1 control so it should be fine. I also set IsEnabled to false.

Comment: as I mentioned, you can set the opacity to zero.

Comment: +1 for the response to the question, -1 for the solution.... Seems like an ugly hack when you have all these other options available (see  response below)

Comment: well it s the most common _hack_ .. anything you d do in this situation is technically a _hack_ anyway. It s just not supported.